# How to set cron as per custom requirements?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I am working on e-commerce site and I need to set cron as per client requirements.

Is this possible for below requirements?

```
Shipment - Shipment Cron only needs to run every 30mins, Monday-Friday 8am-5pm.
Stock - Once per day only, and only Monday - Friday
Orders - 5 mins
Returns - 10 mins
```

I am bit confused about cron run for only monday to friday between specific time.

For shipment its right structure,

```
shipment: */30 8-17 1-5 * *
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can do that, look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24625097/3200799) for more informations

Comment: could you post answer based on above requirements

Comment: Could you please post what you think it should look like ? And what is "Once per day", you need to be specific here

Answer (score 0):

*/30 8-17 1-5 * *

it will work fine as per your requirement